# Crashlytics internals crashing upon logException

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android

We are using Crashlytics logException to report non fatal exception in our application. This is meant to just analyze runtime behaviors. However, it seems to be crashing in Fabric internal class with an IllegalStateException. Function names are obviously obfuscated and it seems to be reported on a wide rage of devices and android versions too. Can someone from Fabric throw some light?

```
  java.lang.IllegalStateException:
    at b.a.a.a.c.a (Fabric.java:273)
    at b.a.a.a.c.a (Fabric.java:524)
    at com.a.a.a.e (Crashlytics.java:188)
    at com.a.a.a.g (Crashlytics.java:371)
    at com.a.a.a.a (Crashlytics.java:207)
```

Comment: Mike from Fabric here and it's unclear what's happening based on that code  snippet. Can you share a full crash report please?

Comment: The stack frames beneath are that of closed source app. But they basically invoke logException()

Comment: I just started seeing this as well.  Doesn't replicate reliably in dev but seeing the crash frequently in production when deployed.  Current working theory is it has something to do with Crashlytics initialization. 
 
@Vairavan any chance you were able to fix this?  Does updating to the most recent version of their library help?

Comment: @Luciano We have updated to latest versions and still have an eye on it.